# Why do I get empty reponse from this http request

Tags: json, node.js, httprequest, httpresponse

I am working on my first node.js script which simply makes a http request to `https://www.swapi.co/api/people/?search=Luke+` and parses the response data.

The endpoint is as follows:

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.swapi.co',
  path: `/api/people/?search=`+firstName+'+'+lastName
};
```

The logic is to get the data from response and parse it to a `person` object:

```
makeRequest(options, function( data, error) {
    let person = data.results[0];
    if (person) {
        let height = person.height;
        let response = person.name + " is " + height + " centimeters tall.";
        callback(null, {"speech": response});
    }
    else {
        callback(null, {"speech": "I'm not sure!"});
    }
  });
```

The definition of `makerequest` function is below:

```
function makeRequest(options, callback) {
    var request = http.request(options, 
    function(response) {
        var responseString = '';
        response.on('data', function(data) {
            responseString += data;
        });
         response.on('end', function() {
            console.log('end: $$$' + responseString + '$$$');
            var responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseString);
            callback(responseJSON, null);
        });
    });
    request.end();
}
```

When I run the script I got the error about parsing the JSON.

```
Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:42:37)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

I tested the endpoint using Postman and got the following JSON as response:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker",
            "height": "172",
            "mass": "77",
            "hair_color": "blond",
            "skin_color": "fair",
            "eye_color": "blue",
            "birth_year": "19BBY",
            "gender": "male",
            "homeworld": "https://www.swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
            "films": [
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/films/2/",
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/films/6/",
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/films/3/",
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/films/1/",
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/films/7/"
            ],
            "species": [
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/species/1/"
            ],
            "vehicles": [
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/",
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"
            ],
            "starships": [
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/starships/12/",
                "https://www.swapi.co/api/starships/22/"
            ],
            "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z",
            "url": "https://www.swapi.co/api/people/1/"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I debug my code, the response data is an empty string. And that explains the JSON error.

What is wrong with my http request? Why am I not getting the correct response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the API you are targeting only supports SSL, but Node's [HTTP](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) library only supports plain-text requests. Try using their [HTTPS](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) library instead.

```
var https = require('https');
var request = https.request(options, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

That URL you are using returns HTML by default.

Instead you need to call: https://www.swapi.co/api/people/?format=json&search=Luke+

(Note the `format=json` parameter)

Comment: I edited `options` with `path: '/api/people/?format=json&search='+firstName+'+'+lastName`, still the same result though

Comment: I'm getting a proper JSON response with and without the `format` parameter. It sounds like your request might actually be getting the wrong response. One thing I noticed is that you don't seem to be attaching the HTTPS protocol to the request, which could lead to an empty response, although I would think Node would follow the redirect just fine.

Comment: Just tried it myself and was able to reproduce the issue you're seeing. Apparently Node's HTTP library doesn't support SSL. See my answer.